# How to enter special characters so that Bash/Terminal understands them?

Tags: macos, terminal, bash

Let's say a folder has a file called `Näyttökuva.png` (for those who are interested, it is ”screenshot” in Finnish). This is what happens:

```
$ ls
Näyttökuva.png

$ ls N*
Näyttökuva.png

$ ls Nä*
ls: Nä*: No such file or directory
```

This also affects the tab-auto-completion. If I start typing `ls N` and press <kbd>tab</kbd> it is correctly expanded to `ls Näyttökuva.png`. But if I start typing `ls Nä` tabbing does nothing.

How can I either:

- configure bash/terminal so it understands special characters
- type the special characters so bash/terminal understands them?

In Terminal's encoding is set to UTF-8 in the Settings–tab and the Encoding–tab is in its default state, ie. UTF-8, Mac OS Roman, ISO Latin 1, ISO Latin 9, Windows Latin 1, ASCII, NextStep + some Asian codings are enabled.

---

Even stranger (though probably not essential for the question):

If I type `ls N`, press <kbd>tab</kbd>, delete characters from the end until it reads `ls Nä` and press <kbd>tab</kbd> again, the command expands to `ls Nättökuva.png` [sic].

If I try deleting the letters second time back to `ls Nä` and press tab it expands to `ls Nätökuva.png`. Third run expands to `ls Näökuva.png`.

For some reason, the 4th run gives `ls Nä̈kuva.png` (notice the umlauts over umlauts). Tabbing the `ls Nä̈` gives `ls Nä̈kuva.png` every time. Nevertheless, it works:

```
$ ls Nä̈kuva.png
Näyttökuva.png

$ history 2
518  ls Näyttökuva.png 
519  history 2
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I think bash is tripping over some anomalies in how accented characters are handled.  You might want to grab some popcorn, because this is going to get technical for a little bit...

Unicode allows some accented characters to be represented in several different ways: "precomposed" as a single "code point" representing the accented character, or "decomposed" as a series of code points representing the unaccented version of the character, followed by the accent(s).  For example, "ä" could be represented either as U+00E4 (UTF-8 0xc3a4, Latin small letter a with diaeresis) or as U+0061 U+0308 (UTF-8 0x61cc88, Latin small letter a + combining diaeresis).

OS X's HFS+ filesystem requires that all filenames be stored in the UTF-8 representation of their [fully decomposed form](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn/tn1150.html%23UnicodeSubtleties).  In an HFS+ filename, "ä" MUST be encoded as 0x61cc88, and "ö" MUST be encoded as 0x6fcc88.

I'm pretty sure what's happening here is that when you type "Näyttökuva.png" at the command line, it's "typing" the characters in precomposed form.  When the file is created, the filesystem decomposes the characters for storage.  Everything is fine so far.  But when you try to use tab-completion starting with "Nä", I think bash is  failing to decompose the "ä" before searching for matches, and of course it doesn't find any.

To illustrate the difference, here's an example of what encoding is used when I just type "Näyttökuva.png" at the command line, vs. what's used when I store it as a filename and use tab completion to fill it in:

```
$ printf Näyttökuva.png | xxd    # This time I pasted the it in from this web page
0000000: 4ec3 a479 7474 c3b6 6b75 7661 2e70 6e67  N..ytt..kuva.png
$ touch Näyttökuva.png           # Also pasted from the web
$ printf Näyttökuva.png | xxd    # This time I tab-completed it after N
0000000: 4e61 cc88 7974 746f cc88 6b75 7661 2e70  Na..ytto..kuva.p
0000010: 6e67                                     ng
```

Now, as for the matter of characters getting lost when deleting and re-tab-completing, I suspect that's closely related.  Specifically, I think bash is "deleting" one code point per press of the delete key, but erasing one character from the Terminal window per press.  Because one of the deleted characters ("ö" this time) consisted of two code points, but only one character, the Terminal display gets out of sync.  Try tab-completing the whole filename, deleting it back to "Näytt", then re-tab-completing: bash seems to think that only the combining diaeresis was deleted, not the entire "ö", so it re-adds the combining diaeresis, but it this time it attaches to the "t":

```
$ echo Näytẗkuva.png 
Näyttökuva.png
```

Note that when I press return, bash actually has the entire filename there; it's just the Terminal display that was confused.

TL;DR bash has some bugs handling decomposable accented characters.

EDIT: after some mulling, I think the only full solution is to fix bash (/wait for its developers to fix it).  There might also be a way to input characters in decomposed form, but I have no idea what that would be.  But I did find some partial workarounds:

1. Drag-and-droping a file from the Finder pastes in its correct form.  Since the Finder gets the filename from the filesystem, it's already decomposed, so it just works.
2. You can actually tab-complete the accented character itself.  For example, if you type "Na" and then tab, it'll match "Näyttökuva.png" because the canonical decomposition of "ä" starts with "a".  But if you have a file named "Narwal.gif" in the same directory, that won't be very helpful...
3. I haven't tested this, but if you bind tab to [menu-complete](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Commands-For-Completion) instead of complete, it should let you tab through possible matches so you can select the one you want even if you can't type the next letter.  (Or you could bind it to a different keystroke, so you can use it only when you need to.)
4. For fixing the problem with the Terminal display getting out of sync, you could bind something to [redraw-current-line](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Commands-For-Moving) -- it won't prevent the problem from happening, but it'll give you a way to resynchronize the display.

Comment: Thanks, I enjoyed the popcorn. I think you've nailed the cause of the problem: using `$ echo -e "N\xC3\xA4*" | ls` (the echo gives `Nä*`) results `Näyttökuva.png`. The problem exist also with the other shells in Mac OS; and with e.g. zsh `ls N` gets auto-completed to `ls Na<0308>ytto<0308>kuva.png`

Comment: I also tried the autocompletion and `ls Nä*` in bash in Xubuntu and it worked properly, so it bugs somewhere between keyboard & OS X & Terminal. I also tested that within Bootcamp partition, but the problem persists (ie. it doesn't happen only with HFS+ files).

Comment: *(Now saw your edit concerning workarounds)* At least the first two work. The #2 is interesting: autocompleting `Na` works, but `Nay` does not (though it is understandable because there actually is `¨` between the `a` and `y`. In Xubuntu `ls Na*` doesn't work (though `Nä*` works so it's really not an issue). Concerning wildcards — one other workaround could be replacing `ä` & `ö` with `a?` and `o?` e.g. `ls Na?y*`. Of course this increases ambiguity, but it might come handy in some cases.

Comment: The reason it works in Xubuntu may just be that the filesystem uses the same form as the terminal interface.  If you do `ls N* | xxd` in Xubuntu, does it give composed or decomposed characters?

Comment: Assuming that Xubuntu stores the filename in composed form, try running the command `touch $'Na\xcc\x88ytto\xcc\x88kuva.png'` and see what happens -- my guess is it'll create a new file with a very very similar name.

Comment: It does give them in composed form when looking at the same file (though I don't know if VMWare Fusion does its own magic in between, nor if it is even the case). Using the command you provided didn't create a new file, it just touched the original. But if I'm working in a folder inside xubuntu's filesystem, it *does* create a different file.

Comment: → Gordon: Latin small letter 1 → Latin small letter a. Too small a typo to fix it ☹.
Thank you for this high quality explanation.

Comment: This isn't bash bug. If you save file in macOS in any program, and give it name 'ä', you will output composed 'ä' and file stores will be composed 'ä'.

Comment: This isn't bash bug, shell shouldn't be opinionated but show filename as the bytes are. If you save file in macOS, and press 'ä', system will output and store composed 'ä'. Only time actual decomposed 'ä' appears is in screenshot. And even if FS would always be decomposed 'ä', which it is not, even then it would be broken behaviour, because then the system should also output decomposed 'ä' when you press the keyboard 'ä'. If you store decomposed, render keypress as decomposed too! I've never in my life seen decomposed 'ä' anywhere but macOS screenshots.

Comment: @ytti I have to disagree. The way bash handled character deletion was clearly wrong, and moreover seems to have been fixed sometime between when I wrote this answer and now (it's working better in bash v3.2.57). I just tested bash v4, and it behaves in yet another way: tab-completion fills in composed characters, but wildcard expansion results in decomposed characters. As for expecting the keyboard driver to render keypresses in the same form the filesystem uses: no, different things use different conventions, you just have to expect that.

Answer (score 4):

This is an old question, and no definite answer. Just workarounds.

However I combined some information from this old guide, and as suggested and instructed [here](http://www.rift.dk/news.php?item.7.6):

I installed a newer bash in my Snow Leopard. After installing it, bash completion works correctly! (Snow Leopard shipped with 3.2.48(1) and MacPorts installed 4.2.45_1). Remember to make the changes in `/etc/shells` and running `chsh`.

Also, because of some other instructions, I have in `.inputrc`:

```
set meta-flag on
set input-meta on
set output-meta on
set convert-meta off
```

Not sure if they are required or not for proper operation.

Comment: You're right: bash 4.2 completes `Nä` (where `ä` is precomposed) to `Näyttökuva.png` but bash 3.2 doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

`iconv` is the solution, that worked for me:

```
ls `echo 'Näytẗkuva.png' | iconv -t UTF8-MAC`
```

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/23226449/1909531